# Refresh fragment after change of switch button on the parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app,i'm using a ViewPager with a PagerTabStrip,on the actionbar i have a `switch button`.
I want to when the `switch button` Changed to true,text of a `textview` that is on the fragment,changed...
 (and also changed to another text when the Switch button is false) 
Here is what i mean: 
[image]

Here is what i do:

> PagerAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public PagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {


        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                    return "Home";
            case 1:
                    return "Test";
            default:
                return "Home";
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentA();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentB();
            default:
                return new FragmentA();
        }
    }





    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

> Main Activity:

```
 switch_button_action.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                boolean State=switch_button_action.isChecked();
                if (State){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = G.preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("SWITCH_BTN_ACTION", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                else{
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = G.preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("SWITCH_BTN_ACTION", false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

> FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
          boolean GetStateSwitchBtnAction =G.preferences.getBoolean("SWITCH_BTN_ACTION", false);
            if(GetStateSwitchBtnAction){
                textview.settext("test");
            }
            else{
                textview.settext("TEST")
            }
         return layout;
        }
```

**my problam is that it doesnt refresh the TextView immediately!** 
after switching to another tab and comeBack to `Home`,it's changed,
but i want to change immediately after `switch button` changed...

Thank you for any help you can provide...

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334063/update-fragment-data-after-newinstance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` extend `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` in PagerAdapter and override following method

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

     return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

and while switching button add below codes

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
pager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Note:** This will refresh your total view pager.

Comment: WOW...it works.Thank you so much Kunu ;) just a question,what is `2` in `etOffscreenPageLimit` ?

Comment: @Johnny It sets the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. So if you write 2 then it will load only 2 pages on either side of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your *FragmentA* implement [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html). This interface defines callback method for when some preference has been changed, so you just need to check if it is a "SWITCH_BTN_ACTION", and then change the text accordingly.

Then you have to register and un-register your fragment for *SahredPreferences* changes in *onCreate()* and *onPause()* methods.

Also, it is a good programmers practice to use String constants for *SharedPreferences* keys. The reason is that you want to define those constants once and just use **them** all over the code. If for some reason you have to change the value of the constant, you only do it in one place otherwise it would be really messy to change every String literal in all the code. This practice applies for other types of variables as well (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants)).

In the end you come up with something like this:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

  public static final String SWITCH_PREF_KEY = "SWITCH_BTN_ACTION";

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
    boolean GetStateSwitchBtnAction = G.preferences.getBoolean(SWITCH_PREF_KEY, false);
    if(GetStateSwitchBtnAction){
      textview.settext("test");
    }
    else{
      textview.settext("TEST");
    }
    return layout;
  }

  @Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    G.preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  @Override public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    G.preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
  }

  @Override public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if(key.equals(SWITCH_PREF_KEY)) {
      if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SWITCH_PREF_KEY)) {
        textview.settext("test");
      }
      else{
        textview.settext("TEST");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)